# awk/bash quoting: print \ in echo

Tags: bash, shell, awk, quoting

We need to print out

targetID="123"

AssayID="456",

```
awk -F\", 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=",";} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$12}' VrtAssay_123_target_456_assay_Detail2.csv > VrtAssay_123_target_456_assay_Detail2_reorder.csv
```

A. We try:

```
printf "awk -F"\""," 'BEGIN{FS=\",\";OFS=\",\";} {print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4,\$5,\$6,\$7,\$8,\$9,\$10,\$11,\$20,\$12,\$13,\$14,\$15,\$16,\$17,\$18,\$19}' VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail2_average.csv > VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail3.csv"
```

B. or echo

```
echo "awk -F"\"", 'BEGIN{FS=\",\";OFS=\",\";} {print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4,\$5,\$6,\$7,\$8,\$9,\$10,\$11,\$20,\$12,\$13,\$14,\$15,\$16,\$17,\$18,\$19}' VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail2_average.csv > VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail3.csv"
```

Both give  (\ is gone)

```
awk -F", 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=",";} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$12}' VrtAssay_123_target_456_assay_Detail2.csv > VrtAssay_123_target_456_assay_Detail2_reorder.csv
```

C. If we try

```
printf "awk -F\\", 'BEGIN{FS=\",\";OFS=\",\";} {print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4,\$5,\$6,\$7,\$8,\$9,\$10,\$11,\$20,\$12,\$13,\$14,\$15,\$16,\$17,\$18,\$19}' VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail2_average.csv > VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail3.csv"
```

These will give an error message of

```
Unmatched ".
```

D. If we try

```
echo "awk -F\\", 'BEGIN{FS=\",\";OFS=\",\";} {print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4,\$5,\$6,\$7,\$8,\$9,\$10,\$11,\$20,\$12,\$13,\$14,\$15,\$16,\$17,\$18,\$19}' VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail2_average.csv > VrtAssay_${TargetIDs}_target_${AssayID}_assay_Detail3.csv"
```

This gives us

```
Unmatched ".
```

Wonder any guru could kindly offer some solutions?

Comment: in your B attempts, note that the backslash is gone because it's used to escape the following `"`.

Comment: @Henry What's your actual question? Why you changed the question? If you have any other queries, try to ask it as another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of these work, you just need to make sure that everything's escaped properly:

```
 $ echo 'awk -F\",'
 $ echo awk -F\\\",
 $ echo "awk -F\\\","
```

The shell's parsing rules are basically:

- Inside `'single quotes'`, everything except for single quotes is interpreted literally; to include a literal single quote, you need to close the single quote and then use double quotes to get that.
- Inside `"double quotes"`, double quotes and backslashes must be escaped with a backslash.  So, a literal double quote is `\"`, a literal backslash is `\\`, and a literal backslash and double quote are `\\\"`.  If you just write `\\"`, that's a literal backslash followed by a closing quote.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes, e.g.:

```
echo 'awk -F\",'
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to,

```
echo 'awk -F\",'
```

It would print as it is if we enclose the input within single quotes.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. However, I edited the question a bit and echo '' might sabotage the following variables  ${TargetIDs} and ${AssayID}.

Comment: Yes, to expand the variables you need to enclose them within double quotes.